# How to run Tensorboard and jupyter concurrently with docker?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, jupyter, tensorboard

I'm starting to learn how to use TensorFlow to do machine learning.  And find out docker is pretty convenient to deploy TensorFlow to my machine.  However, the example that I could found did not work on my target setting.  Which is

Under ubuntu16.04 os, using nvidia-docker to host jupyter and tensorboard service together(could be two container or one container with two service).   And files create from jupyter should be visible to host OS.

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Dokcer
- nvidia-docker

  - Jupyter
  - Tensorboard

Jupyter container

```
nvidia-docker run \
    --name jupyter \
    -d \
    -v $(pwd)/notebooks:/root/notebooks \
    -v $(pwd)/logs:/root/logs \
    -e "PASSWORD=*****" \
    -p 8888:8888 \
    tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu
```

Tensorboard container

```
nvidia-docker run \
    --name tensorboard \
    -d \
    -v $(pwd)/logs:/root/logs \
    -p 6006:6006 \
    tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu \
    tensorboard --logdir /root/logs
```

I tried to mount logs folder to both container, and let Tensorboard access the result of jupyter.  But the mount seems did work.  When I create new file in jupyter container with notebooks folder, host folder $(pwd)/notebooks just appear nothing.

I also followed the instructions in [Nvidia Docker, Jupyter Notebook and Tensorflow GPU](https://www.tyneway.co/2017/03/nvidia-docker-jupyter-notebook-and-tensorflow-gpu/)

```
nvidia-docker run -d -e PASSWORD='winrar' -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3
```

Only Jupyter worked, tensorboard could not reach from port 6006.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing the same problem today.

Short answer: I'm going to assume you are using the **same container** for both Jupyter Notebook and tensorboard. So, as you wrote, you can deploy the container with:

```
nvidia-docker run -d --name tensor -e PASSWORD='winrar'\
                  -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3
```

Now you can access both 8888 and 6006 ports but first you need to initialize tensorboard:

```
docker exec -it tensor bash
tensorboard --logdir /root/logs
```

About the other option: running jupyter and tensorboard in different containers. If you have problems mounting same directories in different containers (in the past there was a bug about that), since Docker 1.9 you can create independent volumes unlinked to particular containers. This may be a solution.

1. Create two volumes to store logs and notebooks.
2. Deploy both images with these volumes.

```
docker volume create --name notebooks
docker volume create --name logs
```

```
nvidia-docker run \
--name jupyter \
-d \
-v notebooks:/root/notebooks \
-v logs:/root/logs \
-e "PASSWORD=*****" \
-p 8888:8888 \
tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu
```

```
 nvidia-docker run \
 --name tensorboard \
 -d \
 -v logs:/root/logs \
 -p 6006:6006 \
 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu \
 tensorboard --logdir /root/logs
```

Comment: Thank you for providing your solution.  First solution works for me!

Comment: Is there any way to avoid: `docker exec -it tensor bash` and rather use sth like `docker exec tensorboard --logs=... ` <-- This command does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can also use the [**ML Workspace**](https://github.com/ml-tooling/ml-workspace) Docker image. The ML Workspace is a web IDE that combines Jupyter, TensorBoard, VS Code, and many other tools & libraries into one convenient Docker image. Deploying a single workspace instance is as simple as:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 mltooling/ml-workspace:latest
```

All tools are accessible from the same port. You can find information on how to access TensorBoard [here](https://github.com/ml-tooling/ml-workspace#tensorboard).